# JavaFx Use reflection with custom annotation to create TableColumn : can't create instance of parameter typed class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, javafx, annotations

In order to facilitate the creation of a TableView with columns in a JavaFX application, I thought of creating an annotation to indicate the field in a model class that I would like to create a TableColumn with cell value type associated with it. Here is the annotation I wrote:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface AsTableColumn {

    String text();
    int index();
}
```

And a sample model class Person like this :

```
public class Person {
    @AsTableColumn(text="Name", index=0)
    private String name;
    @AsTableColumn(text="Age", index=0)
    private int age;

    // setters and getters
}
```

In the native way of creating a TableView with columns in JavaFX, I have to write code like this:

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Name");
TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageCol = new TableColumn<Person, Integer>("Age");

nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<String>(cellData.getValue().getName()));
ageCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(cellData.getValue().getAge()));
```

I have several tables with a lot of columns, so it's annoying to write a lot of code like this which I think there should be a way to simplify it.

When I wrote the annotation processor, I encountered a problem about creating a `TableColumn<T,S>` instance where the T is parametered in the method signature but S is dynamically detected at runtime.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

public class AnnotationProcessor {

    /**
     * Process the model class. 
     * 
     * For the fields declared which have annotation AsTableColumn, create a TableColumn<T,S>
     * instance for it with the detected field type. 
     * @param clas
     */
    public static <T> List<TableColumn<T, ? extends Object>> process(Class<T> clas) {

        for(Field field : clas.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(AsTableColumn.class)) {
                AsTableColumn anno = field.getAnnotation(AsTableColumn.class);
                Class<?> type = field.getType();

                TableColumn<T, /* how to specify the field type here???*/> col = new TableColumn<>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics merely provide compile-time safety, and are not present runtime.

Comment: I would specify the field type by using the Class type

Comment: @SvenOlderaan But the problem is about creating an instance of a generic class at runtime, not getting its runtime generic type

Comment: The only type you can use in the generic would be "Object" sonc you don't know if your field is a String, int, long, etc.

Comment: An *annotation processor* (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html ) is something that runs at compile time. What you do here is just accessing annotations using reflection.

Comment: @fabian yeah that's what I am trying to do exactly. Thx for mentioning the Processor interface. I am not familiar with custom annotations yet. Maybe the name that class is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method

```
private static <T,S> TableColumn<T,S> createTableColumn(Class<S> type, Field field, String text) {
    TableColumn<T, S> col =  new TableColumn<T,S>(text);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        try {
            boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible() ;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            SimpleObjectProperty<S> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<S>((S)(field.get(cellData.getValue())));
            field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
            return property;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    });
    return col ;
}
```

and then just do

```
TableColumn<T, ?> col = createTableColumn(type, field, anno.text());
```

It's not really clear that passing the type gives you much, though. I think you can just do:

```
AsTableColumn anno = field.getAnnotation(AsTableColumn.class);
TableColumn<T, Object> col = new TableColumn<>(anno.text());
col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    try {
        boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible() ;
        field.setAccessible(true);
        SimpleObjectProperty<Object> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(field.get(cellData.getValue()));
        field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
        return property;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

});
```

which is essentially the solution @Thomas posted (and deleted).

FWIW, I usually just use a static utility method for creating table columns:

```
private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
    TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    return col ;
}
```

Then you can do

```
table.getColumns().add(column("Name", Person::nameProperty));
table.getColumns().add(column("Age", Person::ageProperty));
```

If you don't use JavaFX properties, it's pretty easy to adapt this to just make `private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S,T> property);`, but I think you'd have to make special cases for primitive types.

Comment: Ah, that'a a solution. But what if I don't have property fields in the model class, such that I intend to create the cell value factory like (not real code) `col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<type>(cellData.getValue().getFieldValue()));` Now I can't figure out how to create the type parametered instance SimpleObjectProperty with the the field value. ;( Do you have any suggestions?